# Firebase Function & Storage has stopped working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I wrote two functions (~ 07/20/21) using the FB admin SDK to upload a file to FB Storage. It worked for 300+ uploads. I came back to it yesterday (08/11) and it no longer works, and has had no code changes (that I know of).

The FB functions Logs are saying `app ReferenceError: bucket is not defined at Object.writeFileToFirebase (/workspace/uploadUtils.js:12:18)` The storage bucket is defined in my `./firebaseConfig.js` in accordance with the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start).

```
const firebase = require('firebase')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const firebaseConfig = require('./firebaseConfig.js')
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
```

And my two functions are exported from `uploadUtils.js`

```
async function writeFileToFirebase(filename, mimetype, filebuffer) {
    const file = bucket.file(filename)
    const filestream = file.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentType: mimetype
        }
    })
        
    await filestream.end(filebuffer).catch(functions.logger.log(err))
    
    return
}

async function createThumbnail(newthumbname, mimetype, filebuffer) {
    const file = bucket.file(newthumbname)
    const thumbstream = file.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
            contentType: mimetype
        }
    })

    const gm = require('gm').subClass({
        imageMagick: true
    })
    
    gm(filebuffer)
        .resize(240, 240)
        .toBuffer('jpg', (err, thumbbuffer) => {
            thumbstream.end(thumbbuffer).catch(console.log(err))
        })
    
    return
}
exports.writeFileToFirebase = writeFileToFirebase
exports.createThumbnail = createThumbnail
```

Line 12 from the err msg is the `const file = admin.storage().bucket()`

My declaration of `bucket` is at a higher scope than the function call. And I'm using the default bucket I've specified in the `firebaseConfig.js`.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my `bucket` declaration? Or is my problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I needed to move these two lines into the function declaration. They're not inherited... I have no idea why this used to work before this change.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
```